# How to generate arguments of a Clojure macro dynamically?

Tags: macros, clojure, enlive

I am currently developing a small CMS using the wonderful [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) as templating engine. Enlive has a macro called `at` that takes a node (a map) specifying the HTML snippet and an arbitrary number of tuples each consisting of a selector (a vector) and a transformation (a closure).

```
(at a-node
  [:a :selector] a-transformation
  [:another :selector] another-transformation
  ...)
```

Now I want to generate the tuples depending upon incoming data/context. I have tried a lot of different things without success. For example

```
(let [this (repository/u "http://example.com/ACMECorp")
      statements (repository/find-by-subject this)
      context {:depth 1}]
  `(at (snippet-for 'this 'context)
       [root] (set-attr :about (str 'this))
       ~@(loop [rules []
                st statements]
           (if-not (seq st)
             rules
             (recur (conj rules
                          `[:> (attr= :property ~(str (repository/predicate (first st))))]
                          `(content (renderit ~(repository/object (first st)) 'context)))
                    (rest st))))))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

-Jochen

Comment: I suggest looking at the macroexpansion. at the repl: macroexpand-1; in SLIME: slime-macroexpand-1. It may be that you're creating the form incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure is a Lisp, so you can always fallback to building the code you'd want as a list, and call [`eval`](http://clojure.org/evaluation#toc3) on it. I'm not 100% sure about the code you gave, but I'd guess you just want to enclose your whole syntax-quote in an `eval` call.

```
(let [this (repository/u "http://example.com/ACMECorp")
      statements (repository/find-by-subject this)
      context {:depth 1}]
  (eval `(at (snippet-for 'this 'context)
             [root] (set-attr :about (str 'this))
             ~@(loop [rules []
                      st statements]
                 (if-not (seq st)
                   rules
                   (recur (conj rules
                                `[:> (attr= :property ~(str (repository/predicate (first st))))]
                                `(content (renderit ~(repository/object (first st)) 'context)))
                          (rest st)))))))
```

Comment: Yes, eval solved the problem. I did also some quoting wrong. Using at* form was also a piece of the puzzle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if they are interchangeable, but take a look at the at* function. Seems to me that your problem is at being a macro.

**EDIT:** They're not. Call it like this:

```
(at* a-node
  [[:a :selector] a-transformation
   [:another :selector] another-transformation
   ...])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking care. `(at {:tag :p} [:p] (content "foo"))` gives me `({:content ("foo"), :tag :p})` as expected. Unfortunately `(at* {:tag :p} [[:p] (content "foo")])` throws "Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword".